# How to add different CSS to the same HTML tags?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, padding

So I want to have a horizontal rule `<hr>` with a padding of 50px using CSS. However, I already have custom CSS assigned to the `<hr>` tag which already has `padding-bottom:25px; padding-top:100px; padding-left:50px; padding-right:50px;` Which is being used to divide the footer from the main content. So how would I achieve having two different CSS styles for the same element?

P.S. I am using Twitter Bootstrap 3

Comment: Use different classes? This is basic stuff...or am I missing something?

Comment: So what if it's basic stuff? If he needs help, we should give it to him...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually found the answer to what I wanted after all this time.

Basically i did the following:

```
hr.custom {
margin: 10px;
etc...
}
```

Then I used:

```
<hr class="custom">
```

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of different ways to add different CSS to different HTML elements. Mainly, we use IDs and classes, read more about IDs and classes on the [W3Schools website](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_selectors.asp), I use it all the time. Here is an example of using both the ID and class system to style CSS:

The HTML:

```
<p class="coolclass">This is the cool class</p>
<p class="redclass">This is the red class</p>
<p id="strangeid">This is the strange ID</p>
```

The CSS:

```
.coolclass{
    color: blue;
}
.redclass{
    color: red;
}
#strangeid{
    background-color: green;
    color: white;
}
```

**Here is a live example: http://jsfiddle.net/Xanco/8sex7x3p/**

**New live example with HR stylings: http://jsfiddle.net/Xanco/8sex7x3p/2**

Comment: I tried using a new CSS class for hr, didnt seem to work. Let me try again.

Comment: It's okay, we all gotta start somewhere... I've updated the JSFiddle, which is now styling 2 HRs: http://jsfiddle.net/Xanco/8sex7x3p/2/ Don't hesitate to comment if you have any more questions.

Answer (score 0):

Let me make it simple then ..
give it an `id` and style it accordingly

[See it here](http://codepen.io/e6z6a6z/pen/fogCi)

Answer (score 0):

Just for this element, you can add a new class to your `<hr>` like this:

```
<hr class="actualClass newClass">
```

with this CSS:

```
.newClass {
    padding: 50px !important;
}
```